# Django Elastic Beanstalk Varnish Cache

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, varnish, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk with a Django app. It is connecting to an RDS instance on the backend. The app is 99% data driven and most pages don't change, so should be easily cached. However, the site falls over under moderate load and I've tried all caching options available. I think the problem is that I need an external caching mechanism like varnish. However, I don't see any "easy" way to install varnish with elastic beanstalk short of creating a highly customized AMI. Any suggestions?

Btw, the load testing service I'm using is "blitz.io" which puts an intense load on a server quite quickly to simulate being slashdotted, reddited, etc.

Comment: what caching how you tried? have you tried the caching options django provides?

Comment: I've used the Amazon ElastiCache with the Django memcache middleware. I'm currently using the LocMemCache and it seems to have some effect but it's still very slow (relatively speaking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The problem came down to the order of the MIDDLEWARE. I had the GZipMiddleware before the UpdateCacheMiddleware. As soon as I put UpdateCacheMiddleware at the top of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES the caching started to work correctly.